# Looking for specific Visual Studio 2010 add-in for refactoring

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, add-in

I'm looking for an add-in, preferably free, that would reorganize my messy order of fields, properties, methods and place them into contextual region tags such as: Private Fields, Properties, Static Methods, Internal Methods, Events, etc.
I've seen this somewhere once, but I can't find it anywhere now.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you really looking for a refactoring tool? It sounds rather like you need a tidy-up tool.

Check Regionerate: http://www.rauchy.net/regionerate/.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you can do that. Unfortunately, I can't remember any refactoring plugin for free. I like Resharper  ( http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ ) which is the most popular one. And also heard about Code Rush ( http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/ )